# Power BI Report Builder Word Rendering Does Not 'Keep Together'

Tags: reporting-services, ms-word, powerbi, pagination

I am generating a report using Power BI Report Builder (same as SQL Server Reporting Services) and exporting to Word. My data is in a table and within this I have a row group and its contents marked as KeepTogether=True. But when exported the Word Render doesn't respect this and the instances of groups can be split across pages.

How do I get this to behave as I want?

If I render to PDF I get exactly the format I am expecting with with group and its contents on a single  page. This format isn't any use to me because I need editable output so the report can be included as part of a larger document. Hence exporting to Word.

It seems to be because the Word renderer is a 'Soft Page' paginator. Which seems to mean in reality that it generates Word documents as if there are no pages unless you force a page break. Where as PDF rendering does real 'Hard Pages'. This seems mad, there must be someway to generate content for a Word document that actually formats well across pages.

Comment: Could you add some images that show your issue, and the code you are using, to your question?